# convert .mat to .wav

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I need create a wav from .mat file in Matlab. I did this:

```
wavwrite('cap_triger.mat',44100,16,'telo.wav')
```

where cap_trigger.mat is a file which contains the information. With these sentences matlab creates telo.wav but is empty.

This is how I created the file:

```
%captura 
frame_dur = 202e-3;
fs = 44.1e3; 
t_max = 100e-3;

%duración de la ventana de transmisión 
dur_trig = 1e-3;

%duración temporal del pulso de la señal de trigger 
t_samp = 1/fs;  %periodo de muestreo 

%duración del trigger en muestras 
trig_samples = floor(dur_trig/t_samp);
rec_obj = audiorecorder(fs,24,2);
recordblocking(rec_obj,frame_dur);
frame=getaudiodata(rec_obj);
```

Comment: This doesn't actually show how you created the .mat file.  It shows you recording data into a variable 'frame'.  Is that what you want in the WAV file?

Answer (score 0):

[`wavwrite`](http://www.mathworks.es/help/matlab/ref/wavwrite.html;jsessionid=091f756787f2b2b59a3327750ef5) requires a variable, and can not deal directly with .mat-files.

```
load cap_triger.mat
X = dataarray;   % dataarray contained in .mat-file with all the information
                 % or use the variable X contained in the file directly, whatever
wavwrite( X,44100,16,'telo.wav' )
```

I'm not sure and can't test it, but maybe this works as well:

```
wavwrite( load('cap_triger.mat'),44100,16,'telo.wav' )
```

Have a look at [`audiowrite`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html) also, it offers more options and will be available in future release too. (instead of `wavwrite`)

Comment: i try this but when i load .mat produces this error:  ??? Error using ==> load
Unable to read MAT-file C:\Users\epbarreiro\Desktop\GRADIANT\CÓDIGO
MATLAB\cod_Matlab_SISTOLE\v03\cap_trigger.mat: not a binary MAT-file.
Try LOAD -ASCII to read as text.

Comment: how you created that .mat-file?

Comment: from audio capture:                                           %captura
frame_dur=202e-3;
fs=44.1e3;
t_max=100e-3; %duración de la ventana de transmisión

dur_trig=1e-3; %duración temporal del pulso de la señal de trigger
t_samp=1/fs; %periodo de muestreo

%duración del trigger en muestras
trig_samples=floor(dur_trig/t_samp);

rec_obj=audiorecorder(fs,24,2);
recordblocking(rec_obj,frame_dur);
frame=getaudiodata(rec_obj);

Comment: you can edit your posts, I did that for you. Well but it doesn't say how you created the mat-file. And why don't you just use the variables you just mentioned to create the wav-file? What do you need a mat-file inbetween?

Comment: I don't know... this code is not mine. But i need obtain .wav to this .mat to work.

Comment: if `load('cap_triger.mat')` returns an error and doesn't load anything into workspace, the file is broken.